# MySQL correlated subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Having difficulty articulating this correlated subquery.  I have two tables fictitious tables, foo and bar. foo has two fields of foo_id and total_count. bar has two fields, seconds and id.

I need to aggregate the seconds in bar for each individual id and update the total_count in foo. id is a foreign key in bar for foo_id.

I've tried something similar without much luck:

```
UPDATE foo f1 set total_count = (SELECT SUM(seconds) from bar b1 INNER JOIN foo f2     WHERE b1.foo_id = f2.id) WHERE f1.foo_id = bar.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE foo f1
SET total_count = (SELECT SUM(seconds)
FROM bar b1 WHERE b1.id = f1.foo_id)
```

You should have access to the appropriate foo id within the sub-query, so there is no need to join in the table.

Answer (score 1):

In larger data sets, correlated subqueries can be very resource-intensive. Joining to a derived table containing the appropriate aggregates can be much more efficient:

```
create table foo ( foo_id int identity, total_count int default 0 )
create table bar ( foo_id int, seconds int )

insert into foo default values
insert into foo default values
insert into foo default values

insert into bar values ( 1, 10 )
insert into bar values ( 1, 11 )
insert into bar values ( 1, 12 )
    /* total for foo_id 1 = 33 */
insert into bar values ( 2, 10 )
insert into bar values ( 2, 11 )
    /* total for foo_id 2 = 21 */
insert into bar values ( 3, 10 )
insert into bar values ( 3, 19 )
    /* total for foo_id 3 = 29 */

select *
from foo

foo_id      total_count
----------- -----------
1           0
2           0
3           0

update  f
set     total_count = sumsec
from    foo f
        inner join (
                     select foo_id
                          , sum(seconds) sumsec
                     from   bar
                     group by foo_id
                   ) a
            on f.foo_id = a.foo_id

select *
from foo

foo_id      total_count
----------- -----------
1           33
2           21
3           29
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right.

You have the following tables:

- table `foo` - columns: `id` and `total_count`
- table `bar` - columns: `foo_id` (references `foo.id`) and `seconds`

The following query should work (update all `total_count` rows in table `foo`):

```
UPDATE foo AS f1
SET total_count = (
  SELECT SUM(seconds) 
  FROM bar INNER JOIN foo 
  WHERE foo_id = f1.id
);
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with your last `WHERE` clause (`WHERE f1.foo_id = bar.id;`).

Answer (score 0):

This really opens the door to consistency issues. You might consider creating a view rather than mutating the foo table:

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS
SELECT id, sum(seconds) from bar group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer an alternative, I like to use MySQL's nifty multi-table updates feature:

```
UPDATE foo SET total_count = 0;

UPDATE foo JOIN bar ON (foo.foo_id = bar.id)
  SET foo.total_count = foo.total_count + bar.seconds;
```